# CAP table for single founder bootstrapped startup

Tags: investing, start-up, market-capitalization

I have bootstrapped my LLC for two years and am now seeking investment. In this case, I'm considering VC.

[Sequoia](https://www.slideshare.net/PitchDeckCoach/sequoia-capital-pitchdecktemplate) pitch deck templates recommends a CAP table. Since I don't have investors currently, or any outside investment, and do not have a partner, I've never distributed any equity in this company (I own 100%).

Would a CAP table still be valuable? If so, what would someone in my position include in it? If not, what would a first time outside investor want to see, besides my business plan, projected revenue, and other product slides to make a determination?

[This Medium article](https://medium.com/humble-ventures/a-basic-overview-of-the-cap-table-for-first-time-founders-fc9cd5731f48) provides an example table. Again, I haven't considered shares to distribute and don't have investors, so I'm not sure what to include.

[image]

Comment: Your -- small -- CAP table is "Investor X 100%".

Comment: @RonJohn And `Investor X` is just my name? What do I add for common shares, pre-money valuation, etc?

Comment: "*And Investor X is just my name?*"  Yup.  "*What do I add for common shares?*" Something like `100%`, since that's how LLCs work.  As far as `pre-money valuation`: https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/difference-between-premoney-and-postmoney/  The bottom line is that since you haven't had any rounds of funding yet, you'll have to modify it to say something like "Bootstrap Funding" and list how much *you* have invested.